# Facing issues while clicking on some links in a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to click on some categories in a webpage. I could manage to click on the first two categories but got stuck when it comes to initiate the final click. I've given a link leading to the two images in I have marked where to click.

This is the [first link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb16m3z3cdftxbo/Untitled.jpg?dl=0) where there is a sign (marked with pencil) to click on to enter the second portion.

This is the [second link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tdwulpfmn6j86y/Untitled1.jpg?dl=0) where I get stuck when I try to click on the names (I've marked those names with pencil)

This is the [site link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1PCGcGIVnNMtDQtEcWDqBx-G-iT8&ll=32.444813638299706%2C-87.71010306562499&z=8).

Script I've tried with so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("replace_with_above_link")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "i4ewOd-pzNkMb-ornU0b-b0t70b-Bz112c"))).click()
post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='checkbox']")))[1]
post.click()
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".HzV7m-pbTTYe-JNdkSc .suEOdc"))):
    item.click()
driver.quit()
```

My intention is to click the names cyclically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share exception log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to click each item in list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(URL)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "i4ewOd-pzNkMb-ornU0b-b0t70b-Bz112c"))).click()
post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='checkbox']")))[1]
post.click()
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".HzV7m-pbTTYe-JNdkSc .suEOdc")))[1:]:
    item.click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".HzV7m-tJHJj-LgbsSe-Bz112c.qqvbed-a4fUwd-LgbsSe-Bz112c"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".qqvbed-p83tee")))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You are invincible sir. Much appreciated. I would request you to obfuscate the link like i tried above. Thankssssss a lot.